# Users no longer can access site

Tags: permissions

We are having a difficult time trying to find the Administrator of a SharePoint site in a very large organization and in the mean time I am trying to get an answer.

A SharePoint site used to be configured to where users that were logged into a pc with their network credentials and that were given permissions to the site had their credentials pass-through while users that were logged on to a pc that did not have permissions to the site were prompted for credentials.

That recently changed and now users that don't have permissions get the message:

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Does anyone have any idea what could have changed?

Comment: What SharePoint version? What u want  a popup for asking credentials?

Answer (score 2):

"This seems to be an authentication issue where the user is not being identified in Claims based authentication. Try removing and adding a user through PowerShell.

1. first remove user, if user exists using Remove-SPUser command 
   http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff607894.aspx
2. Then add user, using New-SPUser command 
   http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff607868.aspx"

---

`"Error Sorry, this site hasn’t been shared with you.”` is the new “Access denied” in SharePoint 2013.

`“Sorry, this site hasn’t been shared with you.”` It's a basically uncommon error for SharePoint users.

What it actually means that your windows account has not been granted access to the site.

This error is caused by permissions/credentials access problem.

If you have a credential for an account who has rights on the site then, by simply hitting below URL, you can have prompt to login prompt.

If you want to add your account as Site Collection Administrator or to determine the site collection administrator is:

- Let's Log in to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
- Make sure Select Application Management -> Change Site Collection Administrators.
- Select the correct site collection and look at the primary site collection administrator.
  "

---

From a similar post on TechNet: [sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecab4f1a-6191-47e5-973d-e6bab0ccf202/sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: We know the user that is logged on to the pc does not have rights to the site. That is by design because of the way the computers are used. What we would like is when a user launches the website, instead of the SharePoint site giving the message "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.", they get a log on prompt, which is how it used to work.